# Different ways to install / clone a repository

Tags: github, pip

When using github, I know that I can clone a repository by doing something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/name/repostitory.git
```

but I have also seen things like:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/name/repostitory@master
```

Just curious about the differences between the two. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pip Install" command installs your package in your python site packages or any other similar folder, so that you can import modules of that python git repository library in your normal python script. "pip install git+https://github.com/name/repostitory@master" This command assumes that the git repository is structured as a python package.

While "Git clone" just downloads the git repository on your machine. This repository can now be used as a normal git repository on your laptop/machine. It doesn't install any repository as an python package. Repository can belong to any langauge not limited to python